# Friis Transmission Equation for Wideband Transmission

Tags: rf, antenna, radio, microwave

it's known the following **Friis transmission equation**:

$$P_{rx} = P_{tx} \cdot G_{tx}(f) \cdot G_{rx}(f) \cdot \left(\frac{c}{4 \pi R f}\right)^2$$

It's nice but, as far as I'm concerned, it works only for a sine wave of frequency *f* or, with a still good approximation, for narrowband transmission (bandwidth much lower than the carrier frequency).

Now, I'd want to find a similar equation for wideband transmissions, where the transmitted signal spectrum, here called *BW* (Bandwidth) is not much lower than the carrier frequency. If I were to evaluate it, I'd apply the Friis transmission equation for just the little amount of power around the generic frequency *f* of my spectrum *BW*:

$$S_{rx}(f)\cdot df = S_{tx}(f) \cdot G_{tx}(f) \cdot G_{rx}(f) \cdot \left(\frac{c}{4 \pi R f}\right)^2\cdot df$$

where **S** denotes the Power Spectral Density. Now, I'd integrate inside my domain **BW**:

$$P_{rx}=\int_{f_{carrier}-BW/2}^{f_{carrier}+BW/2} S_{tx}(f) \cdot G_{tx}(f) \cdot G_{rx}(f) \cdot \left(\frac{c}{4 \pi R f}\right)^2\cdot df$$

Now, my questions are:

1. **Is my approach correct?** Do you agree with this result?
2. Now let's prove why for a narrowband spectrum such an equation should turn to the common Friis Transmission Equation. If BW is small as compared to the carrier frequency, the integrand can be assumed to be constant. That's a consequence of the first order Taylor Approximation of the Antiderivative ([here the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591655/integration-on-an-infinitesimal-interval)). This means that:

$$P_{rx}= S_{tx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot G_{tx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot G_{rx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot \left(\frac{c}{4 \pi R f_{carrier}}\right)^2\cdot \int_{f_{carrier}-BW/2}^{f_{carrier}+BW/2}df$$

which becomes:

$$P_{rx}= S_{tx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot G_{tx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot G_{rx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot \left(\frac{c}{4 \pi R f_{carrier}}\right)^2\cdot BW$$

If we put:

$$S_{tx}(f_{carrier})\cdot BW = P_{tx}(f_{carrier})$$

we get:

$$P_{rx}=  P_{tx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot G_{tx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot G_{rx}(f_{carrier}) \cdot \left(\frac{c}{4 \pi R f_{carrier}}\right)^2$$

**Do you still agree with the last result?**

Comment: What are you trying to solve when there are much bigger fish to concentrate on like the way an antenna gain and impedance vary dramatically across even a relatively small bandwidth. Then there's the receiver SNR and how that plummets at large bandwidths so, what is the aim of doing this?

Comment: @Andy aka Just a curiosity. That's a question people never told my anything about (maybe because in practice it is less important than other problems, as you've correctly pointed out). But I couldn't bear not knowing the 100% exact answer :)

Comment: @Andy aka: Moreover, I was wondering if such an approach is actually utilized for broadband antennas, as I've seen there are lots of capacitive coupled arrays with with even 1:16 bandwidths

Comment: I think that the way the impedance of an antenna changes with even moderate changes in frequency, I expect that the "interface" filtering to a broadband antenna of some types is going to be fairly sophisticated. In truth, I'm just guessing!!

Comment: Yes, there are arrays out there with 16:1 or better bandwidths.  But very few that I know of that can operate without changes (call it tuning or calibrating for lack of a better term) over more than 200 MHz or 500 MHz instantaneous bandwidth (IBW), though there some.

Answer (score 0):

The Friis equation, like most everything else in engineering, is a linear approximation. I think what you're trying to do here is meaningless from an engineering point of view, because this is a non-real situation. However, consider the following issues

1. The Transmit Antenna gain will vary in both frequency and directionality, so you need to factor in the exact vector direction to the receive antenna.
2. Same for the Receive Antenna.
3. The input impedance of your antenna will vary across the infinite bandwidth you're proposing, which will effect the antenna gain, so that will have to be factored in.
4. Your transmitter output power will vary across the bandwidth into a perfect load, and will vary even more when the nonideal antenna input impedance is taken into account.
5. The same effect of the Receiver input impedance varying across the band, effecting the received signal.
6. The Friis equation also neglects atmospheric effects (humidity, rain, molecular absorption) so there's an atmospheric attenuation that should be taken into account (The ITU has a nice standard for that)

There's probably a couple of other issues I've neglected.

Trying to reduce all those variations to a single number is pointless from a link budget point of view, there's too many variables.